# Unity3D Input.GetKeyUp() polling inefficient?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine

How comes Unity uses polling for all the Input events, is't it very inefficient to check each update loop if there is a new event? If I have 1 mio objects doing it each update cycle I would assume the constant polling would slow down the system significantly..

```
    public void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape)) {
            // escape clicked
        }
    }
```

why is there nothing like this:

```
    public void Start() {
        Input.addKeyUpListener(KeyCode.Escape, delegate {
            // escape clicked
        });
    }
```

Comment: Why would you have a million objects checking for input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that Unity is *not* polling the system every time you call one of those methods - it is instead polling *once* per frame and then caching the value, as evidenced by the [`ResetInputAxes`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.ResetInputAxes.html) function.

This is not the only place Unity does something seemingly insane, but which may be more efficient in the lower levels of code - keep in mind that Unity maintains a lot of customization to the runtime (particularly with garbage collection and construction) that works differently from standard C#.

Note also that callback logic, while great for handlers and generally long-lived objects such as singletons and systems, is not so great for scripts which are normally collected and created several times throughout the lifetime of the game. Since Unity only exposes the ability to make scripts with code, it thus makes more sense to poll, rather than use callbacks which would need attach, handle, and detach behaviours to prevent errors.

Comment: ok good to know, sounds to me that they could still provide some callback logic so that I can write some nicer logic without wrapping the complete Input system myself

Comment: There are actually some problems with callback logic due to the mortality of scripts in general - I'll integrate this note into my answer